# How to install linux-headers package for Linux kernel 4.15.0-2 in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

This will no doubt be an easy question for anyone who knows anything about Debian and Linux, but that apparently doesn't include me...

I need the header files for my kernel, namely 4.15.0-2-686-pae.  But I can't find them anywhere in Debian's package repository.  The only package resembling this is a ["common" package in sid](https://packages.debian.org/sid/linux-headers-4.15.0-2-common) and that does not include all the headers.

Where can I find the headers for this kernel, and why does it seem like they aren't in the repository?

I should add that the kernel was installed from the testing repository originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outdated software gets archived from the repos, but there's a copy of the headers you're looking for [here](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/linux/4.15.11-1/#linux-headers-4.15.0-2-686-pae_4.15.11-1) at the Debian snapshot archive.

---

Please use caution when running outdated software.